# Connections to server not routing properly in Azure signalR client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-signalr

I have set up an Azure SignalR service (ASRS) very similarly to how it is explained here: https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples. The solution is using .Net Framework 4.8 with ASP.NET MVC.  When not using ASRS, it sets up the connection in the Startup class Configuration like this:
`app.MapSignalR();` and that works.  However, when I use `app.MapAzureSignalR(...)` the client cannot retrieve historical messages using the GetChats method in this hub:

```cs
    public class GroupChatService : Hub
    {
        public Task JoinChat(string chatId)
        {
            return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, chatId);
        }

        public object GetChats(string chatId, string date)
        {
            /* Code removed for brevity */
            var chats = model.GetPage(Guid.Parse(chatId), date.ToDate());
            return new { loadMore = model.LoadMore, messages = chats };
        }
```

And this client code:

```js
chatService = $.connection.groupChatService;
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
  chatService.server.joinChat(chatId);
  chatService.server.getChats(chatId, date).then(function (results) {
    //show the results
  }
});
```

The resulting error looks like this:
[image: Chrome devtools websockets error]

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the `MapAzureSignalR` call needed a more specific application name in my multi-tenant environment so that it could route properly.